# How can I show local file system browser for Zend Studio 10?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-studio

I cannot figure out how to show a local system file tree structure in Zend Studio 10. Nearly all IDEs have this capability. Can someone please tell me how I can browse my local system to open a file without having to create a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without explicitly creating a project. I think there is a workaround for this if you are using Linux/OSX. Go to Window > Show View > Remote Systems and create an ssh connection to your local host.

Yes, this is an ugly solution but at least its something!

Comment: Darn unfortunate that Zend doesn't provide a better solution for this. This seems to be the case for a lot of IDE's today, however. I suppose that's why I love NotePad++ so much! Thanks for the answer Julian.